# Bug in Python XORSHIFT simulation

Tags: python, random

I have a Python (Jupyter Notebook) simulation of a XORSHIFT32 PRNG that is producing some unexpected results. I am investigating XORSHIFT performance prior to implementation on an FPGA, so using builtin PRNGs are of no use.

First cell defines the seed and function

```
xorshift_state = 1   # Initial seed

def xorshift():
  global xorshift_state
  xorshift_state ^= xorshift_state << 13
  xorshift_state ^= xorshift_state >> 17
  xorshift_state ^= xorshift_state << 5
  xorshift_state %= 2**32 -1  
  return xorshift_state
```

The 2nd cell then generates the random array and then runs correlation against the first 100 points to check for repeating data sequences.

```
N = 2**16

data = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    data[i] = xorshift()

data = data - int(np.mean(data))
start = data[:100]

match = np.correlate(start,start,mode='valid')

auto = np.correlate(data,start,mode='valid')
```

If I run the first cell and then the second, then the generated data is good. The data set can be extended out to millions of points without correlation peaks (apart from the initial). But if rerun just the 2nd cell, the data generated becomes highly periodic, repeating every 30k samples. Now of course the  state of the PRNG is retained (and only initialised in the first cell) so rerunning the second cell should continue the sequence, but the data generated is different than just running once for twice the number of points.

[image: Correct Correlation Data]

[image: Correlated data]

Adding a line to set the state in the 2nd cell works:
`xorshift_state = 1`    
Of course now the state is not retained between subsequent executions and just produces the same data set each time.

The exact seed value doesn't impact the problem, a more random seed still causes the issue.

Is anyone able to explain why this behaviour occurs?

Comment: I don't know if this explains your strange results, but you don't appear to have implemented xorshift quite correctly.  Truncating the result to 32 bits (necessary due to Python's unlimited-size integers) would normally be written `state &= 2**32 - 1` or perhaps `state %= 2**32`; you've written something that's in between those two, which will surely affect the results.

Comment: @jasonharper, I confirmed that `state &= 2**32 - 1` solves the problem. You can write that as an answer.

Comment: Modulo arithmetic is a relatively slow operation, it’ll probably be faster if you use `&`. Also, to get the same arithmetic results as other language’s implementations the bitmask should be applied after each left shift operation. Otherwise you’re migrating high bits right back into the answer with the intermediate right shift.

Comment: Yes &=  worked. Nice comment on the applying the AND after a left shift too.